# I am making a bot using python and having problem in my python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, whatsapp

```py
from flask import Flask
from googlesearch import search
import requests
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def bot():
    user_msg = request.values.get('Body', '').lower()
    response = MessagingResponse()
    q = user_msg + "geeksforgeeks.org"

    result = []
    for i in search(q, num_results=3):
        result.append(i)

    msg = response.message(f"--- Results for '{user_msg}' ---")
    for result in search_results:
        msg = response.message(result)

    return str(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I am making a bot using python this is my code and i am getting a error
(search got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_result')

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please explain what error you are having.

Comment: Please reformat it, and describe what is Your problem.

Comment: @Mruk I've reformatted it and also mentioned my error

Comment: Do you have the requests module installed?  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: You forgot the comma? from flask import Flask, request

Comment: @ewokx  yes i  have done it

Comment: @Mruk no it's still an error

Comment: @Mruk search got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_results' this is the error now

Comment: your code is still not properly formatted. you have parts of the code not formatted

Comment: @Mruk edited the question now there is some other error of search argument (numresult = 5)

Comment: @ewokx i've edited the question and now there is some other error.

Comment: there's nowere in your code where you use a variable named `num_result`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki so how do i solve it

Comment: It's not clear how you can get an error about a variable that you don't have in your code. Please post the complete traceback of your problem. You just posted what the error says, instead you should copy paste the exact traceback error the computer is giving you and post it formatted as code

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki  this is the error i am getting search got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_results' in line 20 and the line 20 is  for i in search(q, num_results = 3):

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Before and now it;s just an "S"  which is missing.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki If you  can help me please do.

Answer (score 0):

```
name 'request' is not defined
```

means that python can't find the symbol "request"
the reason for that is that you simply didn't import it

Depending on which request you need (depends of the library), you need to import it (It seems like you tried to import requests `import requests`, but request object inside the requests library don't have a value property)
Seeing your code, you probably want request from flash, therefore you just need to change your first line to

```
from flask import Flask, request
```

and request will be defined

If you really want the request from requests, then you have to change your code to

```
from requests import request
```

Comment: search got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_results' at line 21 (this is the error now)

Comment: @Aashinsood if this is the error now a comment in an answer won't attract solutions to this new problem. Edit your question, format your code properly and add your error.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki i've edited the code and mentioned new problem error